# Hover text image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a regular horizontal menu bar. I was wondering if it would be possible to have an image overlap the text upon hovering with the mouse ? I have a horror site that I'm working on, and I think it would be cool to have a bloody handprint appear over the links on the menu bar when hovered over. I know it's possible, because I've seen something similar before, but I need help pulling it off. Thanks in advance.

The first link to the homepage is the image I want to overlay over the texts upon hover.

```
 <div id="header" style="font-size: 15px">

<ul id="menu">
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="Home.html"><img src="logo.png" width="30px" height="25px"/></a></li>
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="Random.html">Random Page</a></li>
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="Characters.html">Characters</a></li>
<li> <a style="color: #207000" href="Timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
<li> <a style="color: #207000" href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
<li> <a style="color: #207000" href="Videos.html">Videos</a></li> 
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="RegalFT.html">Regal Family Tree</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? It's hard to help you without any piece of your code.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. I already have a working menu bar, I just want to know if it's possible to add it to what already exists.

Answer (score 0):

As smdsgn commented on your question, without code you've already tried, it is difficult for others to completely understand what you're trying to accomplish. Regardless, presuming I understand your question correctly I can provide you a couple of pointers.

If you simply want to add an image to your menu bar link when it's hovered over, utilize CSS' `:hover` selector with the `background` attribute (or the `background-image` attribute, if you prefer) as I've done in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/1tbfgr9z/).

```
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #someColour url(yourImage.file) no-repeat left;
  background-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you want more customization, such as hiding the link text when it's hovered over, you can implement some jQuery as I've done in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/6thau2vn/).

```
var hiddenText;

$('li').hover(function() {
  hiddenText = $(this).text();
  $(this).css({'background': '#someColour url(yourImage.file) no-repeat center','background-size': '50px'})
  $(this).text('');
}, function() {
  $(this).css({'background': '#someOtherColour'})
  $(this).text(hiddenText);
})
```

If neither of these pointers provide a solution for you, please add more detail to your question, as well as code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've figured it out on my own. Using a z index in css, I got this html to work how I wanted, so that the "logo" image would fade in and out upon hover.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="Home.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Home</a></li>
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="Random.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Random Page</a></li>
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="Characters.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Characters</a></li>
<li> <a style="color: #207000" href="Timeline.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Timeline</a></li>
<li> <a style="color: #207000" href="Gallery.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Gallery</a></li> 
<li> <a style="color: #207000" href="Videos.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Videos</a></li> 
<li><a style="color: #207000" href="RegalFT.html"><img class="img2" src="logo.png" width="40px" height="35px"/>Regal Family Tree</a></li>
```